# How can I make an Amazon S3 hosted file appear local?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm starting a project using Laravel and hosting my files on Amazon S3. What I want, though, is that if someone links directly to a file, it will appear domain.com/images/file.jpg instead of s3.amazon.com/etc?=file.jpg

How should I best accomplish this using PHP?

Comment: `echo file_get_contents('http://.....file.jpg')`, basically. you'll have to proxy the file, which'll double your bandwidth costs: download the file to your server, then spit it out to the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else facing this delima:

Abstracting it through file_get_contents is the only way.

Or, you can do a bucket subdomain like media.mydomain.com. It's not local, but at least you don't have an ugly url.

Comment: You don't have to use a subdomain - S3 and CloudFront both let you point a domain at them - and your use of "local" doesn't make much sense. `file_get_contents` is a horrid approach, and your users really don't care at all what domain the images are hosted on.

Comment: @ceejayoz It actually matters quite a bit for SEO if your website's content is primary images. And yes, any cname will work on cloudfront, but you cant point your root domain to more than one ip if you also have a website hosted elsewhere.

Comment: "It actually matters quite a bit for SEO if your website's content is primary images." Do you have *any* evidence for that? Sounds like one of the many old wives tales SEO seems to attract. Photo sites like Flickr.com host on subdomains (actually, Flickr even uses `staticflickr.com`) and do just fine for SEO.